# YouTube Premiere countdown animation

Tags: color, video, animation

YouTube has a feature called [Premiere](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9080341?hl=en) that allows creators to publish videos so that they are premiered live, at a particular time, to all viewers.

At the beginning of each premiere is a 2 minute animated countdown with bouncy music

[image: Countdown image]

The countdown has a flat, materialistic, modern style. However, I couldn't help but notice certain parts of the countdown that look similar to monitor calibration tools. Like the black and white stripes below the countdown that get increasingly narrower, and the colored and black and white squares at the top.

My question is, is there a known technical reason for including these certain features at the beginning of the video? Perhaps to help viewers feel comfortable with the resolution or video quality? Or is just an animation style?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This image is know as **test card** (or **test pattern**) and was originally used as a TV test signal. Before 24/7 TV, it was typically shown when the regular broadcast ended. In its beginning it used to be physical test cards at which the camera was pointed and was later replaced by a digital version.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_card) for more context.

**In YouTube's case, I can't really see any value other than an homage to the earlier days of video broadcasting.**

[image]

Comment: "it was typically shown when the regular broadcast ended" Yes, or during broadcasting problems. Instead of putting the channel on black, they'd put in this test card. Often with a message indicating to be patient or that there was a technical malfunction (those black bars at top, middle and bottom doubled as text background).

Comment: Digital? Meh, that was the analog era. Time of great adventure, sense of achievement: it was not given that the image was aligned correctly. To tune the channel correctly so that you had both color AND static-free stereo audio was rite of passage.

Comment: It was also shown in the morning *before* the broadcast, which is essentially what YouTube does here, albeit for a different purpose.

Answer (score 16):

Like the floppy disk icon commonly used to represent the feature of **`saving`** for most of the digital products, the animation visual you mentioned was the opening screen for channels to set up calibration during the use of colored or black and white televisions.

Since you're probably aged below your 30s and haven't ran into occurring of this image on TV, you may not relate any belonging but, there're also common patterns for printers whenever a user first tries to print something out.

> So basically they're using this old shool look since almost most of the people has a memory with it but unfortunately it sometimes become outdated with the new born population's growth and their higher digital awareness.

Comment: I'm below the age of 30 and I saw this image (the pattern) a lot when I was 5-8 years old.

Comment: Actually I didn't mention further since not missing the main point of inquirer's question. You may even run into it on t-shirts displaying it in front. Therefore, I mentioned lower chance of analog awareness instead of digital for the new born population.

Comment: Just to clarify slightly, but this animation isn't an actual test card, it's a homage to them. While there are elements which look like those on test cards, they aren't actually of any use in testing, and furthermore the old test cards were either never animated, or only had very limited moving elements.
Test cards are still in widespread usage in broadcasting for testing and information purposes, even though they are rarely seen transmitted.

Comment: @dosxuk exactly. To be able to mention the inquirer's question at the end `"... Or is just an animation style?"`, I started as `"The animation visual you mentioned ..."` and then concluded with the second paragraph of my answer `"... occurring of this image on TV, ..."` as it's an image.

Comment: I don't really understand why you'd assume Bryan C is under 30, or mention that in the answer. I've seen plenty of test patterns in my life, but this YT Premiere image looks different enough from them that it did not immediately ring a bell for me.

Comment: @amalloy I'm 35 years old and almost saw this million times when I wait channels to start in my childhood. So roughly I assumed "if you're aged younger than your 30's right now". Do you want to kill me for this or just want to mock with it?

Comment: @allamoy yes i am under 30 and have never seen the pattern on TV before. Never watched that much TV when I was young.

Comment: **For Upcoming Readers:** Let's say pandemic is over around this year and after 20-30 years later, you ran into a people who is not aware of COVID-19. It's pretty normal to be relating assumption of this person's born year likely to being later than or around 2020's. And it's again pretty obvious I used this assumption to reasonate inquirer's situation since why he might miss this item. It's of course good to be younger and being younger than 30's as for now, not a barrier to see this footage. There's nothing to take it offensive like I made a facist declaration as @BryanC also even didn't so.

Comment: And @BryanC happy for you to not watching TV much but, like it's almost impossible for a person to not to have a cell phone or a computer for now, it was almost inevitable for a child in my situation to miss watching TV, since I didn't have much toys I suppose. I don't give a chance you took it offensive since you even didn't mention but I'm far away mentioning it as a humiliation. Actually I do feel worse if I'm someone mentioning or praising myself just for I'm older or even wiser. I'm actually trying to contribute to the open source since I believe this way and hoping it helps more people.